# React-Redux conditional variable

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm struggling with react-redux variable for hours...hope someone can help.
The conditional returns to me that the variable order.name is not defined, although everything goes as it should in the reducer and action.
When isLoading === true, it continues rendering {order.name} and I know it is not defined at that point because it takes some time. At that time i set Loader to do it's job..
So it’s not clear to me why he continues to render even though there’s a conditional one that shouldn’t allow it... until isLoading === false.

[Here is console.log of orderDetails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ikinc.png)

```
import { getOrderDetailsAction } from "../actions/orderAction";

const OrderScreen = ({ match }) => {
  const orderId = match.params.id;
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getOrderDetailsAction(orderId));
  }, [dispatch, orderId]);

  const orderDetails = useSelector((state) => state.orderDetails);
  const { order, isLoading } = orderDetails;

  return isLoading ? <Loader /> : <>{order.name}</>;
};

export default OrderScreen;
```

Reducer

```
export const orderDetailsReducers = (
  state = { isLoading: true, orderItems: [], shippingAddress: {} },
  action
) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ORDER_DETAILS_REQUEST:
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: true,
      };
    case ORDER_DETAILS_SUCCESS:
      return {
        isLoading: false,
        order: action.payload,
      };
    case ORDER_DETAILS_FAILED:
      return {
        isLoading: false,
        error: action.payload,
      };
    default:
      return { state };
  }
};
```

Action

```
export const getOrderDetailsAction = (id) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  try {
    dispatch({
      type: ORDER_DETAILS_REQUEST,
    });

    //Getting TOKEN
    const {
      userLogin: { userInfo },
    } = getState();

    //Passing TOKEN
    const config = {
      headers: {
        "auth-token": `${userInfo.token}`,
      },
    };
    const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/orders/${id}`, config);
    dispatch({
      type: ORDER_DETAILS_SUCCESS,
      payload: data,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: ORDER_DETAILS_FAILED,
      payload: error.response.data.msg,
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: Can you check if the request was successful? Looks like the request fails and an action of type `ORDER_DETAILS_FAILED` is dispatched causing `isLoading` to be `false` and `order` to be `undefined`.

Comment: Request is fine.. at start isLoading is undefine then true and then false. And datas are load.,But my conditional doesnt wait isLoading to become false. It fires immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Check redux action for how isLoading state is changed from redux dev tools

Check reducer name -> state.orderDetails (does this exists ?)
`const orderDetails = useSelector((state) => state.orderDetails);`

Also, we can correct this

```
state = { isLoading: true, orderItems: [], shippingAddress: {}, order: {} }

// return entire state and not just isLoading and order
case ORDER_DETAILS_SUCCESS:
  return {
     ...state, <--------
    isLoading: false,
    order: action.payload,
  };
case ORDER_DETAILS_FAILED:
  return {
    ...state,  <---------
    isLoading: false,
    error: action.payload,
  };
```

Comment: order is state which contains orderItems, shippingAddress, isLoading, date, user etc. Reducer is fine and action is doing what it should do. 
At start isLoading is undefine then true and then false. Still i cant figure it out. Tnx for replay

Comment: How come isLoading is undefined ??
Your initial state says isLoading is true

ORDER_DETAILS_FAILED, ORDER_DETAILS_SUCCESS are there constants. or string?

Also ur initial state and ORDER_DETAILS_SUCCESS does not match

Comment: [Here is console.log of orderDetails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ikinc.png) and yes, they are constants

Comment: There are issues this ur reducers
const orderDetails = useSelector((state) => state.orderDetails);

orderDetails is never present in your state